# Manually setting tab name on WPF TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am binding my own ViewModels to a TabControl ItemSource and using templates to customise the content and header behaviour. This all works fine, however in code, when I do TabControl.SelectedTab.Name - this field is blank, as this is something you normally pass in the TabItem construction.

How can I bind a ViewModel property so that it is set as the TabItems Name property?

My tabcontrol XAML

```
<TabControl 
    Margin="0,-2,0,0" 
    x:Name="SelectionTabs" 
    Style="{StaticResource DetailTabControl}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding DetailTabs}" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTab, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DetailTabItem}" >
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type detailTabs:ValuationTabViewModel}">
            <detailTabs1:ValuationTab Margin="0,10,0,10" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

And my viewmodel code

```
 public class TabViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _header;
        private BaseTabContentViewModel _content;

        public string Header
        {
            get => _header;
            set
            {
                _header = value; 
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Header));
            }
        }

        public BaseTabContentViewModel Content
        {
            get => _content;
            set
            {
                _content = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Content));
            }
        }

        public TabViewModel(string header, BaseTabContentViewModel viewModel)
        {
            Header = header;
            Content = viewModel;            
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why on earth would you care about the name property? You've got the viewmodel.

Comment: Name property is mostly used to reference your control from code-behind and shouldn't change - it's among others used by event handlers.

Comment: I've found a way to do this, but I'm >99% convinced it's completely pointless. As Simon says (sorry), names are never set dynamically in WPF; names are used in WPF only to provide an identifier in code behind at compile time. What is the real goal? What are you using the name for?

Comment: Going to guess he's doing work in the codebehind. I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, so details about what you're trying to accomplish is necessary so we can give you alternative strategies.